# Is it possible to use a rich text editor without a CMS?

Tags: javascript, html, text, content-management-system, editor

Rich text editors are commonly implemented as plugins to CMS sites made with joomla, wordpress etc, but can these be used to work with a website that someone makes from scratch with just html php javascript and the works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most CMSes implement a rich text editor like CKEditor. This is written in JavaScript and can be implemented in any web application - for example by using html php and javascript as you suggest.

Check out their [website](http://ckeditor.com/) for more info and examples on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check out [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

Quoting the website:
`"TinyMCE is a platform independent web based Javascript HTML WYSIWYG"`

Answer (score 1):

Sure... take a look at the following links:

- http://www.tinymce.com/
- http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  and if you're looking for one, I suggest http://ckeditor.com/